# Android - asynctask execution order

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with `AsyncTask`, `onPostExecute` method runs before `doInBackground` method finishes its job.

I'm trying to get some data from Firebase database, save it to an array list of "Didattica" objects to be passed to an expandable list view, I have 4 object on the database.

The problem is that `onPostExecute` runs soon after `doInBackground` and then `doInBackground` finishes its job populating the arrayList.

```
public class DidatticaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Didattica> reishiki1 = null;
private ExpandableListView listView1;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter1;
private List<String> listDataHeader1;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHash1;
AsyncTaskDidattica atDidattica;

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference refDidattica1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_didattica);

    listHash1 = new HashMap<>();
    listDataHeader1 = new ArrayList<>();
    listView1 = findViewById(R.id.lvReishiki);
    atDidattica = new AsyncTaskDidattica();
    atDidattica.execute();
    listAdapter1 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader1,listHash1);
    listView1.setAdapter(listAdapter1);
}

private class AsyncTaskDidattica extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Didattica>>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<Didattica>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HashMap result = new HashMap<>();
        reishiki1 = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            refDidattica1 = database.getReference("didattica/1-reishiki");

            refDidattica1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                    Log.i("shinseiLog", "onDataChange" );
                    for (DataSnapshot child1 : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                        Didattica d1 = child1.getValue(Didattica.class);
                        reishiki1.add(d1);
                    }
                    Log.i("shinseiLog", "rei size1: " + reishiki1.size());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
            result.put("reishiki", reishiki1);
            Log.i("shinseiLog", "map size 1: " + result.size());
            return result;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("shinseiLog", "eccezione in doInBackground");
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Didattica>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ArrayList<Didattica> rei = result.get("reishiki");
        Log.i("shinseiLog", "rei size2: " + rei.size());
        for(Didattica r: rei){
            listDataHeader1.add(r.getTitolo());
            listHash1.put(r.getTitolo(),r.getList());
        }
        Log.i("shinseiLog", "header: " + listDataHeader1.size());
        Log.i("shinseiLog", "hash: " + listHash1.size());

        listAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I added some logs to help understand the order:

```
I/shinseiLog: map size 1: 1
I/shinseiLog: rei size2: 0
I/shinseiLog: header: 0
I/shinseiLog: hash: 0
I/shinseiLog: onDataChange
I/shinseiLog: rei size1: 4
```

Last row correctly shows that the arrayList contains all my data, but it is too late.
Why is it executing this way? Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that firebase is async.
So your method...

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
}
```

...is executing in another thread. That's why `onPostExecute` is executed first.

Try this, put the code from `onPostexecute` code inside the method `onDataChange`, [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is already Asynchronous, you dont need to use an AsyncTask to get or upload data.